# Is it possible to create a function in solidity that accepts any number of arguments of any type? Like abi.encodePacked does

Tags: solidity

If it's possible how can they be used later in this function

Comment: Yes, the `fallback` function is an example. Can you provide more context on what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, it's possible, you just need to receive a `bytes` array and decode it yourself.

By the way, the `abi.encode` and `abi.encodePacked` cannot receive more than 12 parameters. To encode more than 12 parameters, you would need to encode a maximum of 12 parameters at a time, and then encode the results of that encoding.

To decode that, then you would need to use something like: `(bytes memory firstPart, bytes memory secondPart) = abi.decode(data, (bytes,bytes))`, and then decode firstPart and secondPart manually.

I implemented a couple of ways that this could be done, one solution better than the other, to have an idea.

For example, take a look at the `encodeNumbersFrom1To24` function, how it needs to encode 12 elements first, then 12 more elements, and then encode the result.

Then take a look at the `decode_v1_incomplete` function. Notice that we can decode many arguments from the `bytes` data but there is a limit on the number of local variables that we can declare (usually 8 and/or 16, depending on compiler options, etc). And there is a limit on the amount of data that `abi.decode` can return also. So we would not be able to decode the whole data and put each data in individual variables.

To solve that, take a look at how the `decode_v2` function is decoding the data. It's using a `struct` to save the data. It copies the 32 bytes of data from the bytes array at a time and decodes it. This is rudimentary because it does a lot of manual work and is not dynamic, but is a way a lot of values into your contract.

Finally, take a look at the `decode_v3_dynamic` function, which decodes the bytes data dynamically. It uses an array to put the data, which is also an option besides a struct.

One thing that you should know in order to decode data, is the type of that data. If you know the type of each data in the bytes array, and their sizes, then you can decode whatever amount of data from it.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

contract Contract {


    // Using a struct to hold the decoded data
    struct DecodedData {
        uint v1;
        uint v2;
        uint v3;
        uint v4;
        uint v5;
        uint v6;
        uint v7;
        uint v8;
        uint v9;
        uint v10;
        uint v11;
        uint v12;
        uint v13;
        uint v14;
        uint v15;
        uint v16;
        uint v17;
        uint v18;
        uint v19;
        uint v20;
        uint v21;
        uint v22;
        uint v23;
        uint v24;
    }

    function encodeNumbersFrom1To24() public pure returns(bytes memory) {
        // If we need to encode more than 12 arguments with abi.encode,
        // then we need to encode a maximum of 12 at a time, them encode the results together
        bytes memory b = abi.encode(encodeNumbersFrom1To12(), encodeNumbersFrom13To24());
        return b;
    }

    function encodeNumbersFrom1To12() public pure returns(bytes memory) {
        // abi.encode does not accept more than 12 arguments.
        bytes memory b = abi.encode(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
        return b;
    }

    function encodeNumbersFrom13To24() public pure returns(bytes memory) {
        bytes memory b = abi.encode(13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24);
        return b;
    }

    function decode_v1_incomplete(bytes calldata b) public pure returns(uint v1, uint v2, uint v3,uint v4,uint v5,uint v6) {

        (bytes memory firstPart, bytes memory secondPart) = abi.decode(b, (bytes, bytes));

        // Since abi.decode has a limit on the amount of data it can return individually and
        // the amount of local variables we are allowed to have, we cannot decode all the data we want in this way.
        (v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6) = abi.decode(firstPart, (uint,uint,uint,uint,uint,uint)); // returns (1,2,3,4,5,6)

    }

    function decode_v2(bytes calldata b) public pure returns(DecodedData memory) {

        // Using a struct to hold the decoded data because we cannot have so many local variables or we get the following error:
        // CompilerError: Stack too deep. Try compiling with --via-ir (cli) or the equivalent viaIR: true 
        DecodedData memory decodedData;

        (bytes memory firstPart, bytes memory secondPart) = abi.decode(b, (bytes, bytes));

        uint from = 0;
        uint increment = 32;

        // TypeError: Index range access is only supported for dynamic calldata arrays.
        // Cannot use array slicing with non dynamic/non calldata, so I need to copy the range manually

        bytes memory b32 = get32Bytes(from, firstPart);

        decodedData.v1 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));
        
        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, firstPart);

        decodedData.v2 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, firstPart);

        decodedData.v3 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, firstPart);
        
        decodedData.v4 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, firstPart);
        
        decodedData.v5 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, firstPart);
        
        decodedData.v6 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, firstPart);
        
        decodedData.v7 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, firstPart);
        
        decodedData.v8 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, firstPart);
        
        decodedData.v9 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, firstPart);
        
        decodedData.v10 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, firstPart);
        
        decodedData.v11 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, firstPart);
        
        decodedData.v12 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        // Resetting
        from = 0;

        b32 = get32Bytes(from, secondPart);

        // Decoding second part
        
        decodedData.v13 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, secondPart);
        
        decodedData.v14 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, secondPart);
        
        decodedData.v15 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, secondPart);
        
        decodedData.v16 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, secondPart);
        
        decodedData.v17 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, secondPart);
        
        decodedData.v18 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, secondPart);
        
        decodedData.v19 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, secondPart);
        
        decodedData.v20 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, secondPart);
        
        decodedData.v21 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, secondPart);
        
        decodedData.v22 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, secondPart);
        
        decodedData.v23 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));

        from += increment;
        b32 = get32Bytes(from, secondPart);
        
        decodedData.v24 = abi.decode(b32, (uint));
        
        return decodedData;

    }

    function decode_v3_dynamic(bytes calldata b) public pure returns(uint[] memory) {

        (bytes memory firstPart, bytes memory secondPart) = abi.decode(b, (bytes, bytes));

        uint[] memory firstPartDecodedElements = decodePart(firstPart);
        uint[] memory secondPartDecodedElements = decodePart(secondPart);

        uint[] memory decodedElementsElements = new uint[](firstPartDecodedElements.length + secondPartDecodedElements.length);

        uint j = 0;
        // Copying decoded first part
        for(uint i = 0; i < firstPartDecodedElements.length; i++) {
            decodedElementsElements[j++] = firstPartDecodedElements[i];
        }

        for(uint i = 0; i < firstPartDecodedElements.length; i++) {
            decodedElementsElements[j++] = secondPartDecodedElements[i];
        }
        // Copying decoded second part
        return decodedElementsElements;

    }

    function decodePart(bytes memory part) public pure returns(uint[] memory) {
        uint countOf32BytesElementsInBytes = part.length / 32;
        uint[] memory elements = new uint[](countOf32BytesElementsInBytes);
        uint j = 0;
        for(uint i = 0; i < countOf32BytesElementsInBytes; i++) {
            bytes memory b = get32Bytes(j, part);
            elements[i] = abi.decode(b, (uint));
            j += 32;
        }
        return elements;
    }

    // Copies 32 bytes of `b` starting at index `fromIndex`.
    function get32Bytes(uint fromIndex, bytes memory b) private pure returns(bytes memory) {
        bytes memory b32 = new bytes(32);
        uint j = fromIndex;
        for(uint i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            b32[i] = b[j];
            j++;
        }
        return b32;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because in solidity the function id requires to know the parameters in advance.

A couple of alternative:

- Accept a `bytes` array and decode yourself the parameters.
- Do not use the solidity ABI an implement your own encoding/decoding routines.